# Сортировка сообщений в ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Есть кастомный адаптер для лист вью в который добавляются сообщения. Последовательность сообщений идет сверху вниз. Как сортировать сообщения в другом порядке, новые снизу?
Такой вот код..

```
ArrayList<DialogSaveData> UpList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new CastomDialog(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
        //присваиваем адаптер списку
        chat.setAdapter(adapter);
 Cursor cursor = db.query("mess", null, "idto =? or idme = ?" , new String[]{idyou.replaceAll("\\s+",""),idyou.replaceAll("\\s+","")}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UpList.add(0, new DialogSaveData(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("idme")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("idto")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data")),
                        myLoginCript.replaceAll("\\s+",""),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status"))

                ));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
```

Comment: почитайте что такое очередь, стек. Быть может, вы найдете там свое решение...

Comment: как вариант, если берём значения из результатов запроса к базе данных, можно просто в запросе к БД применить обратную сортировку по дате (desc). В итоге будем наполнять лист данными в обратном порядке.